# Why are German quotation marks set down, then up? Example: „quotation“

Tags: quotes

English and many other languages do quotation marks like this: “quotation”

German language does it like this (always in hand-writing): „quotation“

What are the (historical) reasons for this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether German SX is the right place for this question, but I'm sure that "primarily opinion-based" is not a good reason to close it, because there's scientific literature dealing with this topic, and explaining the whys and whens.

Comment: [**Comments are not meant to answer**](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/why-should-i-edit-or-answer-rather-than-comment)

Answer (score 3):

*Copied from comment wall:*

Relatively easy answer: that's how things have developed. - This may sound like a tautological explanation, but it is not. It is a brief form of saying: That's always so with historical things: They have developed so, but they also could have developed differently. Clarifying the circumstances of how (rather than why) things have developed as they have developed is the task of the historian. So, a better way to phrase your question would be: "What are the historical circumstances that have contributed to German professional typesetting using those lower and upper quotation marks?" <sup>*[Christian Geiselmann](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/26111/christian-geiselmann)*</sup>

Makes it easy to distinguish the start and end of a quotation. Though I've no clue whether this is the historical reason. – <sup>*[Marzipanherz](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/19201/marzipanherz)*</sup>

This is very deeply connected with the kind of old German writing and typography. Have a look at following URL's and translate if required:

> https://typefacts.com/artikel/anfuehrungszeichen
>   https://www.typolexikon.de/anfuehrungszeichen
>   https://typefacts.com/artikel/anfuehrungszeichen

<sup>[*help-info.de*](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/29913/help-info-de)</sup>

By the way: The "99-66" quotation marks are not the only ones that are used in professional German typography. In many books, especially in such with careful typography, rather the »Guillemets« are used (and exactly in this order which is different from the French and Switzerland usage). Here, too, you cannot really say why, but you can clarify the historical circumstances around this development. <sup>[*Christian Geiselmann*](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/26111/christian-geiselmann)</sup>

@ChristianGeiselmann: "That's how things have developed." Soweit die Aussage nicht Unfug ist, nämlich unterstellend, dass sich die Dinge auch hätten anders entwickeln können, was entweder impliziert, dass sich Geschichte zufällig entwickelt oder esoterisch nach der Willkür eines unerforschlichen, bestimmenden Wesens, ist die Frage nach dem Why die Frage nach Ursachen und Einflussfaktoren. Wieso ist die Vase kaputt? Die Katze hat sie vom Regal gestoßen. <sup>[*user unknown*](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/266/user-unknown)</sup>

@userunkown. Im Beispiel mit Katze und Vase funktioniert die Kausalitätskette natürlich. Jedoch kannst du für komplexe Dinge wie "die Geschichte" (eines Landes, eines Erdteils, der Menschheit, der Napoleonischen Überfälle etc.) nicht mehr mit so einfachen Kausalitäten kommen. Ja, Geschichte hätte sich teils auch anders entwickeln können. Du kannst Faktoren bestimmen, die Entwicklungen beeinflusst haben, aber du kannst keine Kausalitäten finden. In der Physik kennt man, ganz ähnlich, chaotische Systeme, wo kleine Anstöße große Veränderungen nach sich ziehen, deren Ablauf nicht vorhersehbar ist.
Übrigens bist du auch mit deiner Katze schnell am Ende deiner kausalen Weisheit: Wieso ist die Katze aufs Regal gesprungen? Sie hätte auch untenbleiben können. Oder sie hätte fünf Zentimeter weiter rechts landen können, und dann wäre die Vase heil geblieben.
Ich bin beim Suchen nach einer Antwort bisher nur soweit gekommen, dass in der Erstausgabe einer Reihe von Werken Karls Mays, also ca. 1860, ebenfalls Gänsefüßchen unten-oben verwendet wurden, aber noch solche mit geradem Strich, nicht geschweift.
<sup>[*Christian Geiselmann*](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/26111/christian-geiselmann)</sup>

Wikipedia Links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#History
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anf%C3%BChrungszeichen#Typografische_Anf%C3%BChrungszeichen

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79588/discussion-on-answer-by-takkat-why-are-german-quotation-marks-set-down-then-up).